# How to fetch data from two tables in symfony 3 with one query

Tags: database, join, doctrine, symfony-3.2

I have two tables clients and contacts and contacts has client_id as foreign key

```
$client = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('MyBundle:Client')->findAll();
```

This gives the data from table clients but I need data from contacts as well which  has the related client id

Note: I am using embed forms, CollectionType, ArrayCollection

how do I get all clients with respective contacts in one query in symfony 3

Answer (score 0):

you can create a join query like this inside a function into your repository:

```
public function getAllClientWithContacts()
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder();
    $qb
        ->select('c')
        ->from('MyBundle\Entity\Client', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('MyBundle\Entity\Contact');

    return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```

Comment: Thanks @alessandro. However this didn't work for me
I used the following and this worked but I still need to figure out if this is the correct way in symfony 3

public function getAllClientWithContacts()
 {
     $query = $this->getEntityManager()
         ->createQuery(
             'SELECT c,cs
            FROM JimmyBundle:Client c JOIN c.contacts cs ORDER BY c.id ASC'
         );

     try {
         return $query->getResult();
     } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
         return null;
     }
 }

Comment: Yes is another way and this can works, I hope to have helped you to solve your problem!